# how to put loading bar on each template in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loader

i am building an angular app. in that few templates are there and they take quite a lot of time because the domain on which i am running it is slow. so, i want to put a loader bar and when the get requests are complete, then only i should display it. i tried some solutions over the internet but they just are not responding. These are some links that i tried.

https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar

https://github.com/wongatech/angular-http-loader/

What should i do with it?

Comment: Hi friend - Use this link i think it's helpful fro you https://coderwall.com/p/5dpe2w/execute-function-when-ngrepeat-done
thanks

Comment: in this i can execute a function as the ng-repeat is unlooped. i need to show a loader while the $http requests are fetched and then to show it wholly.

Comment: http://nimeshgami.blogspot.in/2015/05/how-to-show-ajax-loading-imageloading.html i think it's work

Comment: its not helping me in angular. it responds to the ajax requests. how am i to use this on angular.